# How do I make a hist() in R for a .dat file which doesn't include header?

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

It's a large volume of data, arround 3mill. entries so for me it is hard to manage, and once I store the values and try the command `hist()` I always get the message `x must be numeric`. I already tried `myval <- read.table('/Users/me/Desktop/only4_columna6.dat',header = FALSE)` but it ain't working either.

Sorry btw i am a bit newbie in R.

Comment: Please share some of your data with `dput(head(myval))`.

Comment: 3M rows isn't big data. The extension `.dat` is used by a *lot* of applications. What does the file contain and what did you actually try? Post the actual code, actual error message. Anything that can fill in memory by definition is *not* big data

Comment: you may want to use `str(myval)` - i assume you used the wrong delimiter so all your values are characters instead of numeric

Comment: `> str(myval)
'data.frame': 3683294 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: chr  "QUAL" "3.75303" "12.6967" "7.1959" ...`

Comment: > dput(head(myval))
structure(list(V1 = c("QUAL", "3.75303", "12.6967", "7.1959", 
"19.2972", "22.0519")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I understand `"QUAL"` shouldn't be included right? How can I avoid it). Btw Thanks everyone for trying to help me.

Comment: Edit your question to include the extra info, don't put it in a comment

Comment: All right sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset DOES include a header, so you should allow for that.

```r
myval <- read.table('/Users/me/Desktop/only4_columna6.dat', header = TRUE)
hist(myval$QUAL)
```

Comment: Thats it, I feel stupid as hell. I considered `header = FALSE` should avoid the header instead of including it. You all helped me a lot, I appreciate it thank you.